# Can I make different shape from css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Can I make this shape from css?

```css
.shape {
  margin: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
}


.shape:before {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: You're close; all you need is the `::after`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```css
.shape {
  margin: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 110px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.shape:before {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
}

.shape:after {
  height: 40px;
  width: 121px;
  border-radius: 90%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So,you have three components, you have already made one using the normal CSS and other (the `circle`) using `before` selector. Now, use the `after` selector to make the third component.

```css
.shape {
  margin: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 155px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
}
.shape:after {
  height: 55px;
  width: 135px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
}

.shape:before {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you.

This is CSS.

```
*
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
 .circle
{
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left:100px;
}
.top
{
    width: 358px;
    height: 115px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 54px;
    position: absolute;
    top:86px;
    left: -28px;
}
.hor
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top:117px;
    left:-50px;
}
```

This is its corresponding HTML.

```
<div class="page">
<div class="circle">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="hor"></div>
</div></div>
```